# Why does McAfee think Stack Exchange is malicious?

Tags: mobile, antivirus

I was surfing Stack Exchange today on my phone and clicked on a question that linked to [skeptics.stackexchange.com](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com) and was promptly greeted with [McAfee telling me the site is malicious](https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi). I've vistited the site before and haven't had any trouble.  Can someone one please enlighten me as to how mobile McAfee determines a site is dangerous?

My phone is a Verizon droid turbo running Android 4.4.4. The AV appears to be Verizon Support and Protection which seems to be using McAfee SiteAdvisor.

Attached are screenshots of the warning pages I was redirected to and a screen shot of the AV about page.

[image: McAffee Site Advisor screenshot]
[image: Verizon Support & Protection screenshot]
[image: McAffee Site Advisor screenshot]

Comment: Link for proof: https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi

Comment: Interestingly, if I change the URL at all (adding a dash which leads to the same content), it comes up clean. https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/are-human-fetal-cells-used-to-produce-pepsi- I wonder if it was cached with a now-deleted spam answer or something. The previous URL is also said to be clean: https://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/http%3A//skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35912/is-pepsi-people

Comment: Because he's on drugs.

Comment: I'd bring it up with Stack Exchange. If there was an actual problem (eg an ad that installed malware), they need to know, and if there isn't, they're in a better position than you to put pressure on McAfee to fix it.

Comment: AFAIK StackExchange thinks that McAfee is malicious, so it's only fair :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone one please enlighten me as to how mobile McAfee determines
>   a site is dangerous?

This can be found in the [SiteAdvisor Site Ratings Policies:](http://www.siteadvisor.com/webmasters/index.html)

> **What Is Rated? How Is It Rated?**
>
> We test the following attributes of a
>   site. Red, yellow, and green scores are computed from the outcome of
>   these tests.
>
> **Downloads** We test downloadable software that is hosted by and directly
>   linked to from a site. We use our award-winning McAfee anti-virus
>   engine to determine if the file includes malware, such as viruses,
>   Trojans or adware. We also test for program behaviors that we deem to
>   be risky or merit a cautionary note. Behaviors can include resetting
>   the browser's home page, adding toolbars or desktop shortcuts or
>   contacting 3rd party Web servers. Based on these results, we score the
>   site's downloads accordingly.
>
> **E-mail practices** We test sites for e-mail practices by entering a
>   valid, unique personal e-mail address into a site's e-mail form. Then
>   we measure any mail that is received at this unique address. We score
>   the site according to the quantity of mail received as well as the
>   "spamminess" of those e-mails. Spamminess is a measure of the mail's
>   commercial content, as well as the presence of tricks used by spammers
>   to try to escape detection by spam filters.
>
> **Browser exploits** We perform tests to detect the presence of exploits
>   on a site. An exploit is any content that forces a web browser to
>   perform operations that the user does not explicitly intend.
>
> **Web reputation** McAfee tests websites for web reputation using the
>   TrustedSource™ system. This system collects security data from tens of
>   millions of sensors located in more than 120 countries. McAfee's
>   proprietary technology analyzes traffic and linking patterns, website
>   behavior, content analysis, site registration and hosting, to develop
>   an overall reputation rating for the website.
>
> **Annoyances** When we visit a site, we record how many pop-ups occur and
>   how many cookies we receive. In addition, we monitor prompts to change
>   a browser's home and search page settings.The presence or cookies is
>   only noted. Cookies do not affect a site's score.
>
> **E-Commerce** McAfee tests sites for the following e-commerce issues:
>
> Phishing: We use proprietary, award-winning real-time phishing
>   software to evaluate whether the site in question is attempting to
>   mimic a legitimate business or financial institution.
>
> Scams: We use a variety of criteria to determine whether a site in
>   question is engaged in questionable business practices, such as
>   selling rogue anti-spyware.
>
> **Links (online affiliations)** We collect information about the URL links
>   posted on a site to determine whether the site is affiliated or
>   effectively directing traffic to another site. We rate a site based on
>   our estimation of the risk users could experience if they used these
>   links to be led to other risky sites.

As for what triggered the rating for the site you are trying to access, we can't really tell as the SiteAdvisor rating itself does not seem to provide any further information on what *specifically* was wrong with the site (no mention of the attributes that they supposedly use to determine the safety of the website).

A simple search for 'siteadvisor false positive' on Google should reveal that SiteAdvisor has a notable history of providing misleading ratings and taking embarrassingly long times to resolve complaints. Given the reputation of StackExchange sites, the rating for the site in question is also probably just a *false positive*.